# Index versus Sequential search performance?

Tags: sql, optimization, indexing, hash

Say I have a database that holds information about books and their dates of publishing. (two attributes, bookName and publicationDate).

Say that the attribute publicationDate has a Hash Index.

If I wanted to display every book that was published in 2010 I would enter this query : select bookName from Books where publicationDate=2010.

In my lecture, it is explained that if there is a big volume of data and that the publication dates are very diverse, the more optimized way is to use the Hash index in order to keep only the books published in 2010.

However, if the vast majority of the books that are in the database were published in 2010 it is better to search the database sequentially in terms of performance.

I really don't understand why? What are the situations where using an index is more optimized and why?

Comment: The closer your query gets to needing to access all the records of the database, the greater the need for your index diminishes.  If you are going to access all records, the overhead of the index is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

It is surprising that you are learning about hash indexes without understanding this concept.  Hash indexing is a pretty advanced database concept; most databases don't even support them.

Although the example is quite misleading.  `2010` is not a DATE; it is a YEAR.  This is important because a hash index only works on equality comparisons.  So the natural way to get a year of data from dates:

```
where publicationDate >= date '2010-01-01' and
      publicationDate < date '2011-01-01'
```

could not use a hash index because the comparisons are not equality comparisons.

Indexes can be used for several purposes:

- To quickly determine which rows match filtering conditions so fewer data pages need to be read.
- To identify rows with common key values for aggregations.
- To match rows between tables for joins.
- To support unique constraints (via unique indexes).
- And for b-tree indexes, to support `order by`.

This is the first purpose, which is to reduce the number of data pages being read.  Reading a data page is non-trivial work, because it needs to be fetched from disk.  A sequential scan reads all data pages, regardless of whether or not they are needed.

If only one row matches the index conditions, then only one page needs to be read.  That is a big win on performance.  However, if every page has a row that matches the condition, then you are reading all the pages *anyway*.  The index seems less useful.

And using an index is not free.  The index itself needs to be loaded into memory.  The keys need to be hashed and processed during the lookup operation.  All of this overhead is unnecessary if you just scan the pages (although there is other overhead for the key comparisons for filtering).

Comment: "*Hash indexing is a pretty advanced database concept;*" I'm curious about that. Hash tables are one the most basic data structures, they're taught in first or second year computer science, and one of the simplest indexes. MySQL and Postgres both support them.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I meant year of publication! It was a poor translation, english is not my first language.

Comment: @Schwern . . . "databases" <> "computer science".  They are NOT one of the simplest indexes, when you get into the world of hash collisions, data skew, data not fitting into memory or distributed databases.  In any case, the "default" indexes in SQL databases are B-trees, based on their prevalence among all databases that support indexes.  They are more general because they support more SQL operations.

Answer (score 1):

Using an index has a performance cost. If the percentage of matches is a small fraction of the whole table, this cost is more than made up for by not having to scan the whole table. But if there's a large percentage of matches, it's faster to simply read the table.

There is the cost of reading the index. A small, frequently used index might be in memory, but a large or infrequently used one might be on disk. That means slow disk access to search the index and get the matching row numbers. If the query matches a small number of rows this overhead is a win over searching the whole table. If the query matches a large number of rows, this overhead is a waste; you're going to have to read the whole table anyway.

---

Then there is an IO cost. ***With disks it's much, much faster to read and write sequentially than randomly***. We're talking 10 to 100 times faster.

A spinning disk has a physical part, the head, it must move around to read different parts of the disk. The time it takes to move is known as "seek time". When you skip around between rows in a table, possibly out of order, this is [random access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) and induces seek time. In contrast, reading the whole table is likely to be one long continuous read; the head does not have to jump around, there is no seek time.

SSDs are much, much faster, there's no physical parts to move, but they're still [much faster for sequential access than random](https://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/693540/Samsung-SSD-970-EVO-Plus-1TB).

In addition, random access has more overhead between the operating system and the disk; it requires more instructions.

So if the database decides a query is going to match most of the rows of a table, it can decide that it's faster to read them sequentially and weed out the non-matches, than to look up rows via the index and using slower random access.

---

Consider a bank of post office boxes, each numbered in a big grid. It's pretty fast to look up each box by number, but it's much faster to start at a box and open them in sequence. And we have an index of who owns which box and where they live.

You need to get the mail for South Northport. You look up in the index which boxes belong to someone from South Northport, see there's only a few of them, and grab the mail individually. That's an indexed query and random access. It's fast because there's only a few mailboxes to check.

Now I ask you to get the mail for everyone *but* South Northport. You could use the index in reverse: get the list of boxes for South Northport, subtract those from the list of every box, and then individually get the mail for each box. But this would be slow, random access. Instead, since you're going to have to open nearly every box anyway, it is faster to check every box in sequence and see if it's mail for South Northport.

---

More formally, the indexed vs table scan performance is something like this.

```
# Indexed query
C[index] + (C[random] * M)

# Full table scan
(C[sequential] + C[match]) * N
```

Where `C` are various constant costs (or near enough constant), `M` is the number of matching rows, and `N` is the number of rows in the table.

We know `C[sequential]` is 10 to 100 times faster than `C[random]`. Because disk access is so much slower than CPU or memory operations, `C[match]` (the cost of checking if a row matches) will be relatively small compared to `C[sequential]`. More formally...

```
C[random] >> C[sequential] >> C[match]
```

Using that we can assume that `C[sequential] + C[match]` is `C[sequential]`.

```
# Indexed query
C[index] + (C[random] * M)

# Full table scan
C[sequential] * N
```

When `M << N` the indexed query wins. As M approaches N, the full table scan wins.

Note that the cost of using the index isn't really constant. `C[index]` is things like loading the index, looking up a key, and reading the row IDs. This can be quite variable depending on the size of the index, type of index, and whether it is on disk (cold) or in memory (hot). This is why the first few queries are often rather slow when you've first started a database server.

---

In the real world it's more complicated than that. In reality rows are broken up into [data pages](https://sqlite.org/fileformat.html#pages) and databases have many tricks to optimize queries and disk access. But, generally, if you're matching most of the rows a full table scan will beat an indexed lookup.

Hash indexes are of limited use these days. It is a simple key/value pair and can only be used for equality checks. Most databases use a [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) as their standard index. They're a little more costly, but can handle a broader range of operations including equality, ranges, comparisons, and prefix searches such as `like 'foo%'`.

The [Postgres Index Types documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html) is pretty good high level run-down of the various advantages and disadvantages of types of indexes.